# multiplication function that multiplies given number with 1 to 10

Tags: python, multiplication

I am trying to write a function that will multiplicate the given number with 1 to 10 and print out the result.
Here is my code:

```
    number = input('Enter a number please: ')
def multiplication(number):
    for i in range(1, 10)
        return print(number =* i)

multiplication(3)
```

and here is the error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax erdoganpc@MacBook-Air-Denis pyShit %
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
>   /Users/erdoganpc/Documents/dev/pyShit/main.py   File
>   "/Users/erdoganpc/Documents/dev/pyShit/main.py", line 3
>       for i in range(1, 10)

can't understand how to solve this problem, **please help me** :(

Comment: Two typos: `=*` should be `*=`, and you need a colon at the end of the `for` line.

Comment: Also with the return inside your for loop will exit the function as soon as it is executed.  There is rarely a reason to return the value of the print function.

Comment: what is the best way to solve this problem? (creating func that will multiply the given number to 1-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try this

```
def multiplication(number):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, 11):
        result.append(str(i) + ' * ' + str(number) + ' = ' + str(number * i))
    return result
```

- Output:

```
['1 * 4 = 4', '2 * 4 = 8', '3 * 4 = 12', '4 * 4 = 16', '5 * 4 = 20', '6 * 4 = 24', '7 * 4 = 28', '8 * 4 = 32', '9 * 4 = 36', '10 * 4 = 40']
```

Comment: answer should be like this (for example i choosed number 4): 1 * 4 = 4, 2 * 4 = 8, 3 * 4 = 12 ... 10 * 4 = 40

Comment: it is a good solution and answer is correct but i also need to see the digits that i multiply my number to, so output should be something like 1 * 4 = 4, 2 * 4 = 8, 3 * 4 = 12 ... 10 * 4 = 40

Comment: if you get solution then click on right & upvote the answer :) @3ckOrHack

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your script, you wrote `=*` instead of `*=`, so the correct way is:

```py
number = input('Enter a number please: ')
def multiplication(number):
    for i in range(1, 10):
        number *= i
    return number

print(multiplication(3))
```

Comment: answer should be like this (for example i choosed number 4): 1 * 4 = 4, 2 * 4 = 8, 3 * 4 = 12 ... 10 * 4 = 40

Answer (score -1):

```
number = int(input('Enter a number please: '))
def multiplication(number):
    for i in range(1, 10):
        number *= i
        print(number)

multiplication(number)
```

```
Enter a number please: 3
3
6
18
72
360
2160
15120
120960
1088640
```

Comment: answer should be like this (for example i choosed number 4): 1 * 4 = 4, 2 * 4 = 8, 3 * 4 = 12 ... 10 * 4 = 40